# do you know any tutorial for MBUnit?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, mbunit

It looks a bit hard to find documentation about MBUnit.  Does anyone know of any tutorials?

Answer (score 1):

I know that there's a book on [Gallio](http://www.gallio.org/) in progress.

Here's a tutorial for [TDD using Rhino.Mocks and MbUnit](http://vkreynin.wordpress.com/2008/12/04/tutorial-to-tdd-using-rhino-mocks-and-systemwrapper/).

Here's an article that [talks about MbUnit GUI tree](http://vkreynin.wordpress.com/2007/09/29/explaining-mbunit-gui-tree/).  It's for MbUnit v2 but you should find it useful for v3.

Comment: book index: http://www.gallio.org/book/XHtml/index.html

Answer (score 1):

More precisely, the [chapter 3](http://www.gallio.org/book/XHtml/ch03.html) of the Gallio book mentionned by Vadim is what you are looking for.

**EDIT:** The *book project* is a bit stuck. But meanwhile, a wiki has been setup. It has a nice tutorial for MbUnit: http://gallio.org/wiki/doku.php?id=getting_started

Comment: Yes, indeed. The book project was rebooted meanwhile.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MBUnit version 2 heres a simple tutorial:

http://blog.dotnetwiki.org/CommentView,guid,504b5250-5220-499a-a2d5-2b51f29b7cd3.aspx